# Updating Running Count on Amazon ECS

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-ecs, elastic-container-registry

I want to update the running count on my Amazon ECS Service. I updated the Desired Count but the running count sticks to one.

```
update_service = client.update_service(
    service=service,
    cluster=response['clusterArns'][0],
    desiredCount=5,
    deploymentConfiguration={
        'maximumPercent': 101,
        'minimumHealthyPercent': 100
    },
)
```

I am currently using boto3 and python to update the desired count. I've tried everything that I can possibly think of.

This is the setup if it's of any help: I have an ECR repo being used by ECS which uses EC2 to server the container. I'm trying to have another EC2 instance update the running count of the ECS Service to serve more users and that's where I am having trouble.

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if there's any issues spinning up a new container?